# Incompatible var types

Tags: c++, winapi

The below errors are @ the GetFullPathName() function

```
1   IntelliSense: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"
2   IntelliSense: argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"
```

I keep getting the above errors when I try to run my program. The variables are of the appropriate type, yet it keeps saying otherwise? Any ideas as to why this is? I don't think it's necessary to type cast them.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    /* Get path of DLL we're loading */
    string name;
    cin >> name;

    const char* DLL_NAME = name.c_str();

    HWND handle = FindWindow(0, L"Calculator");

    if(handle == NULL){
        cout << "Couldn't find process window!" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Process window found, continuing..." << endl;

        DWORD id;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &id);

        char DLL_LOCATION[MAX_PATH] = {0};
        GetFullPathName(DLL_NAME, MAX_PATH, DLL_LOCATION, NULL);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The variables are of the appropriate type, yet it keeps saying otherwise?

No they aren't. `LPCWSTR` and `LPWSTR` are aliases for `const wchar_t*` and `wchar_t*`respectively. You'll have to use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string` for this.

Breakdown of what they mean:

- `LPCWSTR`: Long Pointer to Const Wide String
- `LPWSTR`: Long Pointer to Wide String

Alternatively you could *not* compile your project as unicode (by changing the character set to Multi-Byte IIRC), that way the Windows API will expect "regular" strings.

EDIT: I should note that just like strings have a wide analogue so do `std::cout` and `std::cin` in the form of `std::wcout` and `std::wcin`.

Comment: Alright, just changed the var types to wide strings. I forgot about the win function until just a second ago, so was trying to figure out why I couldn't get user input. Thank you for the quick answer. :)

Comment: @Justin Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2):

You're compiling a Unicode build so all the Windows API functions will be expecting Unicode strings.

You can either:

- change your project settings to do a multibyte build
- switch to using wide strings (`std::wstring` etc)
- call the ANSI api functions explicitly (`GetFullPathNameA` etc)

Answer (score 2):

LPCWSTR is const wchar_t*. You're better off switching to wchar_t as well, because all windows APIs natively work with wchar_t's.