# How to remove error of incompatible variable types in LoadLibrary() function?

Tags: c++, dll, types, loadlibrary

I have one line in my C++ program

```
HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary("DLL_tut.dll");
```

Here I'm getting error saying that **error C2664: 'LoadLibraryW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [12]' to 'LPCWSTR'**

I'm trying to implement program given in link http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855/DLL-Tutorial-For-Beginners.htm

Tried finding some solutions and found this one closest [Incompatible var types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039436/incompatible-var-types) I think, but I'm not understanding that how to covert that string of file, the last answer this question is more appropriate I guess.
Can someone suggest how to remove this error ?

PS: not some homework, new to dlls and trying to understand by myself. stuck in this one last step.

Comment: Can you try wrapping the param in a `TEXT` macro like the example shows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: There are typically ANSI and Unicode versions of functions but with the same function name so using the `TEXT` macro will ensure the passed type is the correct type, or you could pass `L"DLL_tut.dll"` if your project only has a unicode configuration

Comment: what is the difference and which one better to use ?

Comment: the `TEXT` macro will ensure the code will compile in either ANSI or unicode configurations so it's more portable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary(L"DLL_tut.dll");
```

or

```
HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary(_TEXT("DLL_tut.dll"));
```

The thing is that your project is probably compiled with UNICODE macro defined, which causes LoadLibrary to use LoadLibraryW version, which requires Unicode string as a parameter.

Comment: Okay so simple solution is this only ?
Somebody in that link mentioned to change settings. (check SO answer no. 3 link in my question)
That is more efficient way or this one this ?

Comment: @spt025: depends on what you want. If you want to have all your project to use ASCII chars (and ASCII WinAPI functions) unless specified otherwise - change project settings, otherwise - use one of these.

Comment: Okay understood your explanation.
Thank you for your time.